# If a function $f$ is injective then is $g\circ f$ also injective even if nothing is said about $g$?

Tags: functions

I have been struggling with the following two questions:
For any nonempty sets $A,B,C$ and for any functions $f: A\to B$ and $g: B\to C$,
a) if (f) is injective, then $(g \circ f) $ is injective
b) if (g) is surjective, then $(g\circ f)$ is surjective

My main confusion comes from how for example part a, it doesn't say anything about whether or not g is injective. we know if $f(x)$ is injective, then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$. But for g if $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$, and f(x)= 9, g(fx) = 3 or -3. So in this case can i still call $g \circ f$ an injective function?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x, g(x)=x^2$; if $g$ maps $x$ to $\pm\sqrt x $, then $g$ is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is injective, $g\circ f$ doesn't have to be injective too. Suppose that $A$ has more than one point and that $g$ is constant.

Comment: is there a proper way for us to prove it? Because I can't seem to write a proper proof for "it is not injective" but only "it doesn't have to be"

Comment: If $A$ has two distinct points $a$ and $a'$ and $g$ is constant, then $a\neq a'$, but $g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)=g\bigl(f(a')\bigr)$. What else do you need?

Comment: ah i see now i was thinking of how to prove g(f(a)) is not equal to g(f(a')) when f(a)=f(a'). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Both a)  and b) are false. Just consider that $A$, $B$ and $C$ have more than one element each, and a constant function $g$.

Answer (score 0):

a) and b) are false. 
Please look at this function. 
For a) it has to be (g), for b) it has to be (f).
[This is one good anti-exam for both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txy2K.png)